# How to speed up Powershell Get-Childitem over UNC

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

`DIR` or `GCI` is slow in Powershell, but fast in CMD. Is there any way to speed this up?

In CMD.exe, after a sub-second delay, this responds as fast as the CMD window can keep up

```
dir \\remote-server.domain.com\share\folder\file*.*
```

In Powershell (v2), after a 40+ second delay, this responds with a noticable slowness (maybe 3-4 lines per second)

```
gci \\remote-server.domain.com\share\folder\file*.*
```

I'm trying to scan logs on a remote server, so maybe there's a faster approach.

```
get-childitem \\$s\logs -include $filemask -recurse | select-string -pattern $regex
```

Comment: Dir in cmd.exe has always been faster than any other method I have ever used either the FileSystemObject in VBScript or the FileSystem provider in PS. Even to the point that I have written VBScript functions to shell out to cmd.exe Dir for file searching. Recursion just makes it exponentially more pronounced.

Comment: Maybe your PowerShell could call the CMD shell with a command like `dir /b /s \\server\logs\file*.*` to fetch the full paths in a form that PowerShell could easily process?

Comment: @EBGreen - `-recurse` is in there as a carry-over from running against a more local domain. Isn't really needed. Regardless, with or without it is slow. The reason i ask this is that (a) it's a known problem, and (b) it's hard to believe PS is **so** much worse than old CMD.

Comment: I don't know the answer but I will point out that I would expect that simply building the object in PS would take longer than querying acouple of attributes and building a string. PS does waaay more so I'm not suprised that it takes longer to be honest.

Comment: @ewall - i'm doing this to get around it, but honestly it feels just dumb to have to use CMD when one of the selling points of Powershell is as a replacement to CMD. So we have a smart shell and a fast shell. :)

Comment: @EBGreen - oh i totally get that PS is doing quite a bit more, but there should be a way to tell it to do less. Surely they still have the CMD source code to peek at, so they can add a `-fast` option.

Comment: My guess for a reason to the slowness is that PowerShell's `Get-ChildItem` is fetching an entire .NET object of data about each file (just like all of the PS commands which pipe objects), and pulling it over the network wire adds to the time required for fetching the properties and such. CMD, on the other hand, is really just listing the essentials like the path and modified date. I tried using `Get-ChildItem -Filter...`, but it doesn't reduce the info collected for each file--it just reduces the output set by the specified criteria.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/11/04/why-is-get-childitem-so-slow.aspx) is a good explanation on why Get-ChildItem is slow by Lee Holmes. If you take note of the comment from "Anon 11 Mar 2010 11:11 AM" at the bottom of the page his solution might work for you.

Anon's Code:

```
# SCOPE: SEARCH A DIRECTORY FOR FILES (W/WILDCARDS IF NECESSARY)
# Usage:
# $directory = "\\SERVER\SHARE"
# $searchterms = "filname[*].ext"
# PS> $Results = Search $directory $searchterms

[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("Microsoft.VisualBasic") | Out-Null

Function Search {
  # Parameters $Path and $SearchString
  param ([Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)][string]$Path,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$SearchString
  )
  try {
    #.NET FindInFiles Method to Look for file
    # BENEFITS : Possibly running as background job (haven't looked into it yet)

    [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem]::GetFiles(
    $Path,
    [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SearchOption]::SearchAllSubDirectories,
    $SearchString
    )
  } catch { $_ }

}
```

Comment: +1. That doesn't speed up GCI over UNC, but offers a fast workaround. Faster even than CMD DIR in most cases--see test results in my answer. Thanks and i'll accept this answer if no one chimes in with a better one soon.

Comment: Note: It appears that depending on your .NET version, the performance of GetFiles() may degrade exponentially for large directory listings ([msdn ps blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/11/04/why-is-get-childitem-so-slow.aspx))

Comment: Note that you could use [`[System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFiles()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles(v=vs.110).aspx) as of PowerShell v3.  That method was introduced in the .Net Framework 4.0.  This will save you from having to load the VisualBasic assembly.

Comment: Well considering this question is tagged for v2 that wouldn't apply to this question. But it is good to know.

Answer (score 19):

Okay, this is how I'm doing it, and it seems to work.

```
$files = cmd /c "$GETFILESBAT \\$server\logs\$filemask"
foreach( $f in $files ) {
    if( $f.length -gt 0 ) {
        select-string -Path $f -pattern $regex | foreach-object { $_ }
    }
}
```

Then $GETFILESBAT points to this:

```
@dir /a-d /b /s %1
@exit
```

I'm writing and deleting this BAT file from the PowerShell script, so I guess it's a PowerShell-only solution, but it doesn't use only PowerShell.

My preliminary performance metrics show this to be eleventy-thousand times faster.

I tested gci vs. cmd dir vs. FileIO.FileSystem.GetFiles from @Shawn Melton's referenced [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2009/11/04/why-is-get-childitem-so-slow.aspx).

The bottom line is that, for daily use on local drives, `GetFiles` is the fastest. *By far*. `CMD DIR` is respectable. Once you introduce a slower network connection with many files, `CMD DIR` is slightly faster than `GetFiles`. Then `Get-ChildItem`... wow, this ranges from not too bad to horrible, depending on the number of files involved and the speed of the connection.

Some test runs. I've moved GCI around in the tests to make sure the results were consistent.

**10 iterations of scanning `c:\windows\temp` for *.tmp files**

```
.\test.ps1 "c:\windows\temp" "*.tmp" 10
GetFiles ... 00:00:00.0570057
CMD dir  ... 00:00:00.5360536
GCI      ... 00:00:01.1391139
```

GetFiles is 10x faster than CMD dir, which itself is more than 2x faster than GCI.

**10 iterations of scanning `c:\windows\temp` for *.tmp files with recursion**

```
.\test.ps1 "c:\windows\temp" "*.tmp" 10 -recurse
GetFiles ... 00:00:00.7020180
CMD dir  ... 00:00:00.7644196
GCI      ... 00:00:04.7737224
```

GetFiles is a little faster than CMD dir, and both are almost 7x faster than GCI.

**10 iterations of scanning an on-site server on another domain for application log files**

```
.\test.ps1 "\\closeserver\logs\subdir" "appname*.*" 10
GetFiles ... 00:00:00.3590359
CMD dir  ... 00:00:00.6270627
GCI      ... 00:00:06.0796079
```

GetFiles is about 2x faster than CMD dir, itself 10x faster than GCI.

**One iteration of scanning a distant server on another domain for application log files, with many files involved**

```
.\test.ps1 "\\distantserver.company.com\logs\subdir" "appname.2011082*.*"
CMD dir  ... 00:00:00.3340334
GetFiles ... 00:00:00.4360436
GCI      ... 00:11:09.5525579
```

CMD dir is fastest going to the distant server with many files, but GetFiles is respectably close. GCI on the other hand is a couple of thousand times slower.

**Two iterations of scanning a distant server on another domain for application log files, with many files**

```
.\test.ps1 "\\distantserver.company.com\logs\subdir" "appname.20110822*.*" 2
CMD dir  ... 00:00:00.9360240
GetFiles ... 00:00:01.4976384
GCI      ... 00:22:17.3068616
```

More or less linear increase as test iterations increase.

**One iteration of scanning a distant server on another domain for application log files, with fewer files**

```
.\test.ps1 "\\distantserver.company.com\logs\othersubdir" "appname.2011082*.*" 10
GetFiles ... 00:00:00.5304170
CMD dir  ... 00:00:00.6240200
GCI      ... 00:00:01.9656630
```

Here GCI is not too bad, GetFiles is 3x faster, and CMD dir is close behind.

**Conclusion**

`GCI` needs a `-raw` or `-fast` option that does not try to do so much. In the meantime, `GetFiles` is a healthy alternative that is only occasionally a little slower than `CMD dir`, and usually faster (due to spawning CMD.exe?).

For reference, here's the test.ps1 code.

```
param ( [string]$path, [string]$filemask, [switch]$recurse=$false, [int]$n=1 )
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("Microsoft.VisualBasic") | Out-Null
write-host "GetFiles... " -nonewline
$dt = get-date;
for($i=0;$i -lt $n;$i++){
  if( $recurse ){ [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem]::GetFiles( $path,
      [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SearchOption]::SearchAllSubDirectories,$filemask
    )  | out-file ".\testfiles1.txt"}
  else{ [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FileSystem]::GetFiles( $path,
      [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SearchOption]::SearchTopLevelOnly,$filemask
    )  | out-file ".\testfiles1.txt" }}
$dt2=get-date;
write-host $dt2.subtract($dt)
write-host "CMD dir... " -nonewline
$dt = get-date;
for($i=0;$i -lt $n;$i++){
  if($recurse){
    cmd /c "dir /a-d /b /s $path\$filemask" | out-file ".\testfiles2.txt"}
  else{ cmd /c "dir /a-d /b $path\$filemask" | out-file ".\testfiles2.txt"}}
$dt2=get-date;
write-host $dt2.subtract($dt)
write-host "GCI... " -nonewline
$dt = get-date;
for($i=0;$i -lt $n;$i++){
  if( $recurse ) {
    get-childitem "$path\*" -include $filemask -recurse | out-file ".\testfiles0.txt"}
  else {get-childitem "$path\*" -include $filemask | out-file ".\testfiles0.txt"}}
$dt2=get-date;
write-host $dt2.subtract($dt)
```

Comment: @Kiquenet - what do you mean? There is full source at the end of the answer.

Comment: `More or less linear increase as test iterations increase.` Getfiles and CMD took 3x as long to run the test twice, while GCI took 2x as long.  If this is the linear increase expected then there will be a point when GCI becomes faster again, are you sue you didn't accidentally run GetFiles/Dir 3x times and GCI twice?

Answer (score 2):

I tried some of the suggested methods with a large amount of files (~190.000). As mentioned in Kyle's comment, `GetFiles` isn't very useful here, because it needs nearly forever.

cmd dir was better than `Get-ChildItems` at my first tests, but it seems, GCI speeds up a lot if you use the `-Force` parameter. With this the needed time was about the same as for cmd dir.

P.S.: In my case I had to exclude most of the files because of their extension. This was made with `-Exclude` in gci and with a `|` where in the other commands. So the results for just searching files might slightly differ.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an interactive reader that parses `cmd /c dir` (which can handle unc paths), and will collect the 3 most important properties for most people: full path, size, timestamp

usage would be something like `$files_with_details = $faster_get_files.GetFileList($unc_compatible_folder)`

and there's a helper function to check combined size `$faster_get_files.GetSize($files_with_details)`

```
$faster_get_files = New-Module -AsCustomObject -ScriptBlock {
    #$DebugPreference = 'Continue' #verbose, this will take figuratively forever
    #$DebugPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
    $directory_filter = "Directory of (.+)"
    $file_filter = "(\d+/\d+/\d+)\s+(\d+:\d+ \w{2})\s+([\d,]+)\s+(.+)" # [1] is day, [2] is time (AM/PM), [3] is size,  [4] is filename
    $extension_filter = "(.+)[\.](\w{3,4})" # [1] is leaf, [2] is extension
    $directory = ""
    function GetFileList ($directory = $this.directory) {
        if ([System.IO.Directory]::Exists($directory)) {
            # Gather raw file list
            write-Information "Gathering files..."
            $files_raw = cmd /c dir $directory \*.* /s/a-d

            # Parse file list
            Write-Information "Parsing file list..."
            $files_with_details = foreach ($line in $files_raw) {
                Write-Debug "starting line {$($line)}"
                Switch -regex ($line) {
                    $this.directory_filter{
                        $directory = $matches[1]
                        break
                    }
                    $this.file_filter {
                        Write-Debug "parsing matches {$($matches.value -join ";")}"
                        $date     = $matches[1]
                        $time     = $matches[2] # am/pm style
                        $size     = $matches[3]
                        $filename = $matches[4]

                        # we do a second match here so as to not append a fake period to files without an extension, otherwise we could do a single match up above
                        Write-Debug "parsing extension from {$($filename)}"
                        if ($filename -match $this.extension_filter) {
                            $file_leaf = $matches[1]
                            $file_extension = $matches[2]
                        } else {
                            $file_leaf = $filename
                            $file_extension = ""
                        }
                        [pscustomobject][ordered]@{
                            "fullname"  = [string]"$($directory)\$($filename)"
                            "filename"  = [string]$filename
                            "folder"    = [string]$directory
                            "file_leaf" = [string]$file_leaf
                            "extension" = [string]$file_extension
                            "date"      = get-date "$($date) $($time)"
                            "size"      = [int]$size
                        }
                        break
                    } 
                } # finish directory/file test
            } # finish all files
            return $files_with_details
        } #finish directory exists test
        else #directory doesn't exist {throw("Directory not found")}
    }
    function GetSize($files_with_details) {
        $combined_size = ($files_with_details|measure -Property size -sum).sum
        $pretty_size_gb = "$([math]::Round($combined_size / 1GB, 4)) GB"
        return $pretty_size_gb
    }
    Export-ModuleMember -Function * -Variable *
}
```

Comment: NOTES: I think New-Module was added in `powershell 3.0`, be sure to test if you're using 2.0 or earlier.  Also because this is parsing a digest from a cmd command there's a very small possibility the directory could be wrong or files could be missing, specifically if unusual characters in any of the folder names made it not match the `(.+)` part of the regex.  If you run into errors please let me know, and for anything mission critical please validate the full path using your preferred method

Comment: in the line $files_raw = cmd /c dir $folder\*.* /s/a-d where does $folder come from?

Comment: Good catch, I'll fix it now