# Quickly scan large directory / drive with powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to scan a shared network drive, containing many thousands of files, for only Word files that haven't been modified in the past year.  While what I wrote works, it is extremely slow. I have multiple drives I need to scan and it take hours.  Is there anything I can do to speed it up?

`gci \\RemoteServer\ -filter *.docx -recurse -force | %{write-progress -Status $_ -Activity "Scanning old Word files...";$_} | ? {$_.lastwritetime -ge '1/1/13' -AND $_.lastwritetime -le '12/30/13'} | measure-object`

I did see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196937/how-to-speed-up-powershell-get-childitem-over-unc) but am not sure how I would / could apply the date range to that search.

I also know that the `write-progress` slows it down, but since the first run took several hours I wanted to know it was alive.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Write-Progress will slow you down.

Comment: @Colyn1337 Did you read my entire post? ... "I also know that the write-progress slows it down, but since the first run took several hours I wanted to know it was alive."  I added write-progress after the first run since it was already taking hours and I wanted to see it was still running correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Switch -Wildcard ((cmd /c dir \\Server\Share\*.docx /S /A-D) -match 'Directory of|^\d\d/\d\d/2013')
  {
   '*Directory of*' {$directory = $_.replace(' Directory of ','')}
   Default          {'{2} {0}\{1}' -f $directory,($_ -split '\s+',4)[-1],$_.split(' ')[0] }
   }
```

Comment: Tested locally, ran noticeably faster.  If it doesn't choke on a full scan I'll mark as answered.  Thanks.

Comment: If you have remoting enabled, it will run faster if you run it locally on the target machines using Invoke-Command, and local drive paths.