# Script that checks if folder exists on users PC while counting files of those folders

Tags: powershell, count

I would like to create a script that both check if 2 folders exist (C:\Program Files (x86)\MS and C:\Program Files\MS) on several PC names (Names listed to a systems.txt file) and count how many files there are on that path.

As I am a beginner I could not write more than the following:

```
  Get-Content C:\reports\systems.txt | 
Select-Object @{Name='ComputerName';Expression={$_}},@{Name='MS Installed';Expression={ Test-Path "\\$_\c`$\Program Files (x86)\MS"}},@{Name='number of files';Expression={$numberp}}

  Get-Content C:\reports\systems.txt | `
   Select-Object @{Name='ComputerName';Expression={$_}},@{Name='MS Installed';Expression={ Test-Path "\\$_\c`$\Program Files (x86)\MS"}},@{Name='number of files';Expression={$numberp2}}
```

This returned the PC name + a ''true'' if the file exist or ''false'' if it does not. In addition to this, how can I count the number of files contained on each path of each pc?

```
ComputerName      MS Installed     number of files
------------   ------------------- ---------------
PCname1                True              0
PCname2                True              0
PCname3                True              0
PCname4                False             0
```

I would be so grateful if you could help me figure it out.

Comment: Where do you populate `$numberp` I see no logic for this. You expression needs to count the files which it currently does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use [IO.DirectoryInfo enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413343.aspx) (available since .NET framework 4, it's built-in since Win 8/10; [installable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17851) on Win7/XP), which is much faster than Get-ChildItem on network paths. We'll count the number of items using a plain loop statement, which is faster than Measure-Object while being just as memory-efficient since we don't allocate an array of all files anywhere.

```
Get-Content R:\systems.txt | ForEach {
    $pc = $_
    $numFiles = 0
    foreach ($suffix in '', ' (x86)') {
        $dir = [IO.DirectoryInfo]"\\$pc\c`$\Program files$suffix\MS"
        if ($dir.Exists) {
            foreach ($f in $dir.EnumerateFiles('*', [IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories)) {
                $numFiles++
            }
            break
        }
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'ComputerName' = $pc
        'MS Installed' = $dir.Exists
        'Number of files' = $numFiles
    }
}
```

If .NET framework 4 is not desirable, use the fast [VisualBasic's FileIO.FileSystem assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7208713) or the slow Get-ChildItem so the above code would become compatible with the ancient PowerShell 2:

```
Get-Content R:\systems.txt | ForEach {
    $pc = $_
    $numFiles = 0
    foreach ($suffix in '', ' (x86)') {
        $dir = [IO.DirectoryInfo]"\\$pc\c`$\Program files$suffix\MS"
        if ($dir.Exists) {
            Get-ChildItem $dir -recurse -force | ForEach {
                $numFiles += [int](!$_.PSIsContainer)
            }
            break
        }
    }
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        'ComputerName' = $pc
        'MS Installed' = $dir.Exists
        'Number of files' = $numFiles
    }
} | Select 'ComputerName', 'MS Installed', 'Number of files'
```

Comment: Hi wOxxOm 
Many thanks for your kind support. I have tested both and they seem to work perfectly! Time to study the code now :~)