# Get-ChildItem vs. direct use of the .NET Framework's [System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles() method with UNC paths

Tags: .net, powershell, filesystems

When using a UNC path (ex: `\\machine\share\dir`), I can get a file list when using the `dir` command (`Get-ChildItem`) from a UNC path, but if I try `[System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles`, I get an empty list (not an error, just no items).  I thought that PS was built on the .NET framework.  Does anyone know why `Get-ChildItem` would work with a UNC path while the .NET `GetFiles` method returns an empty list?

Comment: GetFileSystemEntries method would be the analog you're looking for. Also, the difference is that NET class is faster,  especially with UNC parts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**`[System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles()` returns only *files*, whereas [`Get-ChildItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) (and its built-in alias `dir`) by default returns both files *and* directories.**

<sup>Therefore, calling `[System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles()` on a directory that has sub-*directories* only (no *files*) yields "nothing" (an empty string array)).</sup>

Another way of putting it, *loosely* speaking: `Get-ChildItem` is the *union* of [`[System.IO.Directory]::GetFiles()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfiles(v=vs.110).aspx) (akin to `Get-ChildItem -File`, PSv3+) and [`[System.IO.Directory]::GetDirectories()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getdirectories(v=vs.110).aspx) (akin to `Get-ChildItem -Directory`, PSv3+), or, more directly, the counterpart to [`[System.IO.Directory]::GetFileSystemEntries()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfilesystementries(v=vs.110).aspx).

Another option is to use the .NET 4+ (available in PSv3+) filesystem-item *enumeration* APIs, such as [`[System.IO.Directory]::EnumerateFileSystemInfos()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383504(v=vs.110).aspx). For an example, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44378894/45375) of mine.

There are many specific differences between `Get-ChildItem` and direct use of the `[System.IO.Directory]` type, however, notably that `Get-ChildItem` returns *objects* rather than strings and that `Get-ChildItem` skips *hidden* items by default (`-Force` must be used).

As is typical, choosing between using PowerShell's own cmdlets and direct use of the .NET Framework is a tradeoff between convenience and performance.
The latter will generally be faster, and in the case at hand, that is especially true with UNC paths in PowerShell versions 1 and 2 - see [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2009/11/04/why-is-get-childitem-so-slow/).

<sup>Tip of the hat to [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom) and [Mike Sherrill 'Cat Recall'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/562459/mike-sherrill-cat-recall) for supplemental information.</sup>