# Streamline Powershell Searching Script

Tags: powershell, search, scripting

I have written the following script out to search 9 directories across my network.  It functions as needed but is ungodly slow (i assume due to the amount of places its going).  My question to you, as i am not very experienced with powershell, is there any way that something could be "streamlined" to speed up the end result?  It seems pretty messy having all these sources.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$source1 = "\\Server_IP\d$\Folder\Err"
$source2 = "\\Server_IP\d$\Folder\Err"
$source3 = "\\Server_IP\d$\Folder\Err"
$source4 = "\\Server_IP\d$\Folder\Err"
$source5 = "\\Server_IP\d$\Folder\Err"
$source6 = "\\Server_IP\d$\Folder\Err"
$source7 = "\\Server_IP\d$\Folder\Err"
$source8 = "\\Server_IP\d$\Folder\Err"
$source9 = "\\Server_IP\d$\Folder\Err"

Get-Childitem –Path $source, $Source2, $Source3, $Source4, $Source5, $Source6 , $Source7, $Source8, $Source9 -Include *SEARCHITEM* -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to speed up Powershell Get-Childitem over UNC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196937/how-to-speed-up-powershell-get-childitem-over-unc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Start-Job` to spin up separate background processes to carry out the job against each `$source`:

```
$Sources = @(
    "\\Server_IP\d$\Folder\Err"
    "\\Server_IP\d$\Folder\Err"
    "\\Server_IP\d$\Folder\Err"
    "\\Server_IP\d$\Folder\Err"
    "\\Server_IP\d$\Folder\Err"
    "\\Server_IP\d$\Folder\Err"
    "\\Server_IP\d$\Folder\Err"
    "\\Server_IP\d$\Folder\Err"
    "\\Server_IP\d$\Folder\Err"
)
$Files = $Sources |ForEach-Object {
  Start-Job -ScriptBlock { 
    $args |Get-ChildItem -Filter *SEARCHITEM* -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
  } -ArgumentList $_.FullName
} |Wait-Job |Receive-Job
```

`$Files` will now contain the relevant files from all the locations in `$sources`

Comment: Hey thanks! ill definitely try this out!  Im looking to list directories that contain a folder name of *searchitem*, rather than the actual files in that path.  How would I adjust the $files to reflect a path rather than the files themselves?

Comment: Thank you for the help. I am hoping you may be able to assist with reformatting the $Files to list the folder path instead of items specifically?  I've been toying with it, but no matter what I do I am unable to output the search results.