# Remove-Item with Recurse and Exclude multiple subdirectories

Tags: powershell, bamboo

I am trying to create a script to delete all files and directories within a folder, **except** for specified folders and their content.

Example tree:

```
test/
    - images/
        - folder_to_keep/
        - misc/
        - blah/
    - some_other_folder/
        - another_to_keep/
        - snafu/
```

I've searched for this specific question with little luck. I've tried:

```
Remove-Item .\test\* -Exclude (".\test\images\folder_to_keep", ".\test\some_other_folder\another_to_keep") -Recurse
```

but that still deletes everything.

FYI, I am trying to run this script in a build job on an Atlassian Bamboo server if that helps anyone. See: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo0515/script-894237366.html. If there is a better way using their options (Shell, Windows PowerShell, /bin/sh or cmd.exe) that would be great too.

Edit: robocopy might be an option also. The basic problem is that I need to mirror the source and the destination paths, but there are folders in the destination that must remain unchanged (they get filled from another process).

Comment: Would `get-childitem | select-string -notMatch | remove-item` work?

Comment: If the specified folders are scattered about (different depths, with children, etc) it might be easier to first move the specified folders a new empty folder, then delete what's left, then move the new folder.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Tbh, I am very inexperienced with powershell/windows commands. If there's an easier/better way using the other options, I'm all for it.

Comment: Using the pipe as Paul suggests seems to me the fastest way to do this - either select-string or using where-object { $_.Name -notmatch etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-Exclude` applies only to leaf elements, not the full path. For example, a filter `-Exclude 'foo'` would remove a folder named "foo" from the result list, *but not its files or child folders.*

Combine the parent paths you want excluded in a regular expression and use a regexp (non-)match.

```
$excludes = "$($pwd.Path)\test\images\folder_to_keep",
            "$($pwd.Path)\test\some_other_folder\another_to_keep"

$re = ($excludes | ForEach-Object {[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join '|'

Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force | Where-Object {
    $_.FullName -notmatch "^$re"
} | Remove-Item -Force
```

Comment: Thank you for replying...and formatting my question! I will give this a shot. I will mark solved if I can get it working properly.

Comment: Well, it looks like it would work, but it is making the build process drag to a halt. Maybe too many files to sort through? I might have to find a different solution.

Comment: @ksumarine [Related](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2009/11/04/why-is-get-childitem-so-slow/). [Also related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7196937/1630171).

Comment: With that said, not processing files (`Get-ChildItem -Directory -Recurse -Force`) should already speed up processing considerably.