# how to make this script run faster for a huge fileshare?

Tags: powershell

New here and getting to learn powershell, so forgive me for mistakes.
A senior staff had left abruptly and i was tasked to finding out all folders in DFS that the employee had access to (security reasons).
Couldn't find a script that does that for me (to scan 14TB of DFS shares to find what folders user or his group memberships may have access to), so just wrote my own.
Its working fine but too slow for my liking, wondering if it can be tuned to run faster.

running it in 2 parts to save folders first, then user each folder path to get ACL permissions and filter against the username to a csv (with ~ as delimiter to avoid messing with commas).
using powershell 5.1

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
#$rootDirectory = 'C:\temp'
$rootDirectory = '\\?\UNC\myServer\myShare'
$scriptName = 'myACL'
$version = 1.0
$dateStamp = (Get-Date).ToString('yyyyMMddHHmm')
$scriptDirectory = $PSScriptRoot
$log = $scriptDirectory + "\" + $scriptName + "_dirList_v" + $version + "_"+$dateStamp+".log"
"Path" | Out-File $log

function getSubfolders ([String]$arg_directory, [string]$arg_log)
{
    $subFolders = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $arg_directory -Directory -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -expandProperty FullName
    $subFolders | Out-File $arg_log -append
    #"just before loop" | Out-File $arg_log -append
    foreach ($folder in $subFolders)
    {
        #"working on $folder" | Out-File $arg_log -append
        getSubfolders $folder $arg_log
    }
    #"returning from function" | Out-File $arg_log -append
}

#part1
getSubfolders $rootDirectory $log


#part2
$dirListSourceFile = $log
$log2 = $scriptDirectory + "\" + $scriptName + "_permissionList_v" + $version + "_"+$dateStamp+".csv"
$i=0



"Sr~Path~User/Group~Rights~isInherited?" | Out-File $log2

Start-Sleep -s 2

Import-CSV $dirListSourceFile | ForEach-Object{
    $i++
    $path = $_.path.Trim()
    $Acl = get-acl $path | Select *

    ForEach ($Access in $Acl.Access)
    {
        
        if($Access.IdentityReference.value -eq "mydomain\user1" -or $Access.IdentityReference.value -eq "mydomain\sg1" -or $Access.IdentityReference.value -eq "mydomain\sg2" -or $Access.IdentityReference.value -eq "mydomain\sg3" -or $Access.IdentityReference.value -eq "mydomain\sg4")
        {
            "$i~$path~$($Access.IdentityReference.value)~$($Access.FileSystemRights)~$($Access.IsInherited)" | Out-File $log2 -append
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The easiest way to speed it up would be to run it locally on the server and not via UNC path. ;-)

Comment: i do am running it locally, but still using UNC path to avoid the 256 character limit on paths.

Comment: AFAIK This limit only exist for 32 bit app. For current apps you just have to enable the support for long paths [Maximum Path Length Limitatio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry)

Comment: hehe you already implemented the fix for ```path too long```: ```'\\?\UNC\myServer\myShare'``` you can do the same for local paths, e.g. ```\\?\C:\directoy``` - once done you can run it locally - use this technique in combination with the parameter pspath

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the comments, if you have the possibility to run the code locally do it. You can use the same technique, as you did in case of the UNC path, for local paths - e.g. `\\?\C:\directoy`

see:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=registry

Furthermore you did write a recursive function but thats not necessary in this case as get-childitem has this feature built in. Currently you call for each subfolder get-childitem again and also you write each time a log entry to the disk. Its faster to collect the data and write it to the disk one time, e.g.:

```
#Get paths locally and add \\?\ in combination with -pspath to overcome 256 string length limit, add -recurse for recursive enumeration
$folders = get-childitem -PSPath "\\?\[localpath]" -Directory -Recurse -ErrorAction:SilentlyContinue
#Write to lofile
$folders.fullname | set-content -Path $arg_log
```

Also if you want to optimize performance avoid unecessary operations like this:

```
$Acl = get-acl $path | Select *
```

get-acl gives you a complete object and you take it send it over the pipeline and select all (*) properties from it. Why? This `$Acl = get-acl $path` is enough.

Finally you may use io classes directly, instead of get-childitem - see:

[How to speed up Powershell Get-Childitem over UNC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196937/how-to-speed-up-powershell-get-childitem-over-unc)

Comment: +1 on avoiding | select *
I'm using my own recurse precisely so that i can write to disk as dir names are fetched.
this is due to scanning a 14TB DFS share, so that i can see progress, and have some output if not all if script is interrupted.